# Tracking Youtube Embedded videos with SiteCatalyst Omniture

Tags: api, youtube, adobe, adobe-analytics

So, I have tried for ages now it seems to track multiple Embedded videos on my test-site with Adobes SiteCatalyst.

Below is the link with documentation I've used

https://gist.github.com/KamalChembath/00106eb266c91777c32e

The problem I've tried to solve is that I want to be able to listen/track already embedded videos, and not actually create the videos using the API and THEN listen to them.

But the documentation "appends" an iframe created by the API into an empty div that needs to have the same id as the iframe id.

But since the embedded video is already there, I don't need this part, obviously.

Please feel free to ask questions if I'm not clear enough.

Anyone had this issue before?

Below is some changes I've made to try to make it append two players into two divs(trying to hack the code I've already got) Putting it all into a for-loop.

Regards everyone!

```
<div id="player123">
iframe id="player123" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-yKNuU8biQo?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="player1234">
<iframe id="player1234" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VyK-JhjPguY?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
 var iframeObject = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
 for ( var i = 0; i < iframeObject.length; i++){
 var youtube_id = iframeObject[i].id;

var player;

 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 player = new YT.Player(youtube_id, {
 videoId: iframeObject[i].src.substring(29, 40),

events: {
'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
'onError' : onPlayerError
}
});
 }
</script>
```

Comment: It would be much easier to set this up if you are using DTM and then you can basically follow the instructions here http://www.cardinalpath.com/youtube-video-tracking-with-google-tag-manager-v2-and-universal-analytics-a-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late answer. This was greatly appreciated :D